# OAuth with RestSharp

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to get a access token from FedEx Api Authorization (OAUTH2). The documentation lists this in the example:

```c#
var client = new RestClient("https://apis-sandbox.fedex.com/oauth/token");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer ");
request.AddHeader("X-locale", "en_US");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

// 'input' refers to JSON Payload
request.AddParameter("undefined", input, ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

I am confused on the format for

```c#
request.AddParameter("undefined", input, ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

What exactly is "undefined" & input supposed to be? Input is supposed to be a json object, but is the string supposed to be just "undefined"?
The fedex api documentation I am following is at:
https://developer.fedex.com/api/en-us/catalog/authorization/v1/docs.html#operation/API%20Authorization

Comment: Could you please provide a link to the API documentation?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are referring to examples on [this API description](https://developer.fedex.com/api/en-us/catalog/address-validation/v1/docs.html) page. It looks like they have a bug in their C# code samples. They seemingly use [Redoc](https://github.com/Redocly/redoc) for generating API documentation and code examples. It's a `javascript`-based tool, so that would explain an `undefiuned` value.

RestSharp [expects](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/dev/docs/usage/parameters.md#request-body) `Content-Type` value as a name of the `RequestBody` parameter:

> The name of the parameter will be used as the `Content-Type` header for the request

So my understanding is that the C# example should read as following:

```cs
var client = new RestClient("https://apis-sandbox.fedex.com/address/v1/addresses/resolve");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer ");
request.AddHeader("X-locale", "en_US");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

// 'input' refers to JSON Payload
request.AddParameter("application/json", input, ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```